# develop oauth2 application using golang that allows signin from other applcation

Tags: go, oauth, oauth-2.0

what is the best way to develop an application which allows clients to authenticate their user by logging into my application.
Like we can do google sign in, i want give myapp signin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a lot of packages. A very good package, which wraps all the different providers is [goth](https://github.com/markbates/goth). I wrote a [short tutorial using goth with Buffalo](https://blog.gobuffalo.io/buffalo-tutorial-create-a-site-with-github-auth-629582e2763e), which you could use an example.

Comment: i want create a login which i can provide other apps to sign-in using my login.Can this be achieved using buffalo

Comment: Yes, but the OAuth part does not need the Buffalo package around it. It depends on what exactly you plan. If I understand you correct you plant something like https://auth0.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of packages to do it. For example https://github.com/go-oauth2/oauth2